# How to get the maximum and minimum values of a given type

Tags: julia

How does one get the maximum and minimum values of a Number type like an Integer or a Float?

```
max_value(Int)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For questions like this, you will be best served by looking at the julia docs https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.typemin

Specifically for this question, `typemin(Int)`, and `typemax(Int)` should do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, julia's docs aren't especially googleable, but if you go to juliadocs, you can search for functions, or just read through the relevant sections.

Answer (score 7):

But `typemax(Float64)` gives 'Inf' which is probably not what the author wanted.
The trick is to use `prevfloat(typemax(Float64))` which is not that obvious.

```
julia> typemax(Float64)
Inf
julia> prevfloat(typemax(Float64))
1.7976931348623157e308
```

Comment: One way to define the maximal element is the one that ensures `min(maximal, x) == x`. For `Float64`, that element is indeed `Inf`.

Comment: ...or just just `floatmax(Float64)`